# JsonReaderException when triggering an action from a Teams card

Tags: microsoft-teams

We're currently failing the validation of our Teams app as there is an error when triggering an action from a Teams card. This used to work and we can't find out what has changed.

When a user creates a task in our application (awork) we send a notification to Teams to show this card. We have several interaction options (none of which work) that are supposed to send data back to our API and trigger an action.

In this case, when the user adds a comment and clicks send, the Teams-internal call fails with an error. This action request is never sent to our API.

[image: The card and error as shown in the Teams UI]

This is the card JSON we're sending to the Teams API:

```json
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "➕ <b>Sebastian</b> created a new task",
    "themeColor": "85A0C6",
    "title": "➕ <b>Sebastian</b> created a new task",
    "sections": [
        {
            "text": "<a href='https://....awork.io/tasks/46333b4b-.../details'>Teams Test</a>"
        }
    ],
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "ActionCard",
            "name": "Choose assignee",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "@type": "MultichoiceInput",
                    "id": "assignees",
                    "title": "Choose assignee...",
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "display": "Sebastian",
                            "value": "3da590f9-..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "name": "Choose",
                    "target": "https://app.awork.io/api/v1/teamshooks/actions",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json-patch+json"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "aw-workspaceid",
                            "value": "121d57f8-..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "body": "{"integrationId":"0aac5109-7ee2-...","event":"set-assignee","eventData":"{{assignees.value}}","entityType":"task","entityId":"46333b4b-..."}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "ActionCard",
            "name": "Set a deadline",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "@type": "DateInput",
                    "id": "duedate",
                    "title": "Set a deadline..."
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "name": "Set",
                    "target": "https://app.awork.io/api/v1/teamshooks/actions",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json-patch+json"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "aw-workspaceid",
                            "value": "121d57f8-..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "body": "{"integrationId":"0aac5109-...","event":"set-due-date","eventData":"{{duedate.value}}","entityType":"task","entityId":"46333b4b-..."}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "ActionCard",
            "name": "Set a status",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "@type": "MultichoiceInput",
                    "id": "statuses",
                    "title": "Set a status...",
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "display": "In Progress",
                            "value": "7fc7257d-..."
                        },
                        {
                            "display": "Review",
                            "value": "80c7257d-..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "name": "Set",
                    "target": "https://app.awork.io/api/v1/teamshooks/actions",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json-patch+json"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "aw-workspaceid",
                            "value": "121d57f8-..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "body": "{"integrationId":"0aac5109-7ee2-...","event":"set-status","eventData":"{{statuses.value}}","entityType":"task","entityId":"46333b4b-..."}"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "ActionCard",
            "name": "Add a comment",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "@type": "TextInput",
                    "id": "comment",
                    "title": "Write a comment...",
                    "isMultiline": true
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "@type": "HttpPOST",
                    "name": "Send",
                    "target": "https://app.awork.io/api/v1/teamshooks/actions",
                    "headers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json-patch+json"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "aw-workspaceid",
                            "value": "121d57f8-..."
                        }
                    ],
                    "body": "{"integrationId":"0aac5109-...","event":"comment","eventData":"{{comment.value}}","entityType":"task","entityId":"46333b4b-..."}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the request I see in the network tab from the Teams UI to the Teams API:

```
POST https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/19:1a...@thread.tacv2;messageid=16787.../167.../executeAction
{
    "inputParameters": [
        {
            "id": "assignees",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": "duedate",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": "statuses",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": "comment",
            "value": "Test"
        }
    ],
    "actionId": "b74386dd-...",
    "potentialAction": "{\"@type\":\"HttpPOST\",\"@id\":\"b74386dd-...\",\"name\":\"Send\",\"target\":\"https://app.awork.io/api/v1/teamshooks/actions\",\"headers\":[{\"name\":\"Content-Type\",\"value\":\"application/json-patch+json\"},{\"name\":\"aw-wid\",\"value\":\"121d57f8-...\"}],\"body\":\"{\\\"integrationId\\\":\\\"0aac5109-...\\\",\\\"event\\\":\\\"comment\\\",\\\"eventData\\\":\\\"{{comment.value}}\\\",\\\"entityType\\\":\\\"task\\\",\\\"entityId\\\":\\\"4e1064dd-...\\\"}\",\"bodyContentType\":\"\"}",
    "name": "action/connector",
    "integrationId": "i4l...",
    "meta": "{\"connectorSenderGuid\":\"c38a72ce-...\",\"providerAccountUniqueId\":null,\"connectorConfigurationAlternateId\":\"ecf9df...\"}",
    "clientInfo": {
        "locale": "en-us",
        "country": "us",
        "platform": "Web",
        "clientVersion": "1415/1.0.0.2023031528"
    }
}
```

This request results in a 200 status code, but returns an error response:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "actionId": "b74386dd-...",
    "properties": {
        "displayMessage": "",
        "errorCode": "JsonReaderException"
    }
}
```

What I can see is that, in this request, `{{comment.value}}` is not replaced by the text of the comment input. But isn't that what Teams is supposed to do? Why is this failing?

I am expecting this call to succeed without an error code and the `{{comment.value}}` to be replaces with `Test` in my example. This body should then be POSTed to our API.

Comment: Could you please share your card JSON to test at our end?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT thanks for checking, I added the JSON to my question.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT any update on this? We've tried deleting the connector and setting everything up again. It works for the engineer that uploads the app and connector to the teams account, but fails for everyone else in the testing team.

Comment: Are there any more details we can provide?

Comment: Could you please share the repro steps to try at our end? How you are sending this card to Teams? Are you sending this card via webhook or is there any other way.

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT, we're making a POST request to the webhook URL we receive from Teams during the setup. It's https://aworkio.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/fd4d3ece... for example.

Comment: Generally, what we do is configure the connector, which gives us the webhook URL, which we store in our database. When a user then creates a task in awork, we send a MessageCard with a list of potential actions to the webhook URL as shown above. It arrives in Teams correctly, shows the message including all actions. It also includes the target URL on our API, as well as the header and body to send once the user makes an action. However, this request to the Teams API fails with the JsonReaderException. We never get this request, so it fails somewhere between the Teams UI and API.

Comment: I'm happy to jump on a call to explain in detail.

Comment: We are able to repro your issue. We have raised a bug for this. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92150070/232413659-a49e03e3-22d9-4b89-86a2-358099876c32.png

We will let you know once we get any updates on it.

Comment: Thank you @Nivedipa-MSFT. Is there anything we can do or try in the meantime to get this to work? Thanks

Comment: There doesn't seems to be any way to work here.